# Running multiple folders for commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So Im pretty new to JS and Id like to have multiple folders for different commands. I only have one file for commands called "befehle". This is the current command handler for me.

```
const { readdirSync } = require("fs")

const ascii = require("ascii-table")

const table = new ascii().setHeading("Command", "Load Status");

module.exports = (client) => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`./befehle/`).filter(f => f.endsWith(".js"));

    for (let file of commands) {
        let pull = require(`../befehle/${file}`);

        if (pull.name) {
            client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
            table.addRow(file, "✔")
        } else {
            table.addRow(file, '❌ Not working');
            continue;
        }

        if (pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases))
        pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name));
    }

console.log(table.toString())
```

}

I really have no idea how to have multiple folders, can anyone take a look please?

Answer (score 2):

At first, I'm sorry for not correcting **your** code, but this my **suggestion** for you:

Before I show you my **command handler**, let's take a look at how your folder structure should be for this:

```
commands
│
├──admin-commands
│     ban.js
│     kick.js
│    
├──fun-commands
│     ping.js
│     meme.js
│ 
└──misc
      test.js
```

*(File names are just examples)*

Now that you have structured your **commands folder** like this, you can use this as your **command handler**:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const rootDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const fileArray = [];

    function readCommands(dir) {

        const __dirname = rootDir;

        // Read out all command files
        const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));

        // Loop through all the files in ./commands
        for (const file of files) {
            // Get the status of 'file' (is it a file or directory?)
            const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));

            // If the 'file' is a directory, call the 'readCommands' function
            // again with the path of the subdirectory
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                readCommands(path.join(dir, file));
            }
            else {
                const fileDir = dir.replace('\\', '/');
                fileArray.push(fileDir + '/' + file);
                // fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(cmdFile => cmdFile.endsWith('.js'));
            }
        }
    }   
};
```

I think the comments are explaining the process pretty well. But let's move on!

---

After you pasted that into your project you still need to call the `readCommands()` function...

```js
readCommands('commands');

    for(const file of fileArray) {
        const command = require(`../${file}`);

        if(command.name) {
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }       
    }
```

The parameter `commands` is the name of your **root command folder**. So if you decide to give it another name, e.g. 'commandFolder', you need to pass that name as parameter!

#### But dont copy & paste it yet! I want you to understand how this works:

In the **command handler code**, rigth underneath the `module.exports` I'm creating an **array** called `fileArray`. This stores all your **command files** the code above has found. **Now** we **loop through** this **array**, **import** the command and **check** if it's empty or not.

If it's **not** empty, we'll **set** this command to `client.commands`, so you can **get** it later in your code, when you need to **execute** it.

#### If you know how it works...

...you can paste this into the same file as the 'main code' of the **command handler**, so that both code snippets are in the same file. Also make sure to paste this **inside of** the `module.exports` block, not outside of it ;)