# Keep getting error for undefined reading execute on client.commands.get in discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've just gotten into coding using visualstudio and discord.js (i wanted to make a discord bot) so i decided to follow a tutorial on it. Im learning allot but my knowledge is simply too small to solve this problem, ive searched everywhere but i cant find a clear answer.

This is my code (or the tutorial code ;p):

```
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    

    if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    } else if (command === 'group'){
        client.commands.get('group').execute(message, args);
    }
});
```

This is the ping.js file code:

```
module.export = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "This is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args){
        if(command === 'ping'){
            message.channel.send('pong!')
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error i keep getting:

```
C:\Users\User\DiscordBot\index.js:33
         client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute')
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Again im new so i aplogize in advance if the answer is very obvious...
Thanks for reading!

Comment: `client.commands.get('ping')` is `undefined`.

Comment: I understand its undefined, but i dont know how to define it and i cant find anything about it online. (or im searching the wrong thing)

Comment: [How is JavaScript different from Java?](https://java.com/en/download/help/java_javascript.html)

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely different

Comment: @SparkyLife Did you add the command handler code (if so can you edit your post to include the command handler code)

Comment: Have you even added the command to the client?

Comment: Are you following the instructions here? https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html Your code does not seem to match how discord.js documentation says to add a command. It looks like you are expecting ping.js to add the command, but I don't think you are following the process required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you never added your commands to `client.commands`, so I'd recommend adding a **command handler**.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68175145/13685706) I already explained how to implement a **command handler**. Take a look at it, it should fix you current and maybe further problems :)

*In case the URL should no longer be available at some point in time, I'll paste the answer in here as well*

---

Before I show you my **command handler**, let's take a look at how your folder structure should be for this:

```
commands
│
├──admin-commands
│     ban.js
│     kick.js
│    
├──fun-commands
│     ping.js
│     meme.js
│ 
└──misc
      test.js
```

*(File names are just examples)*

Now that you have structured your **commands folder** like this, you can use this as your **command handler**:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const rootDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);

module.exports = (client) => {
    const fileArray = [];

    function readCommands(dir) {

        const __dirname = rootDir;

        // Read out all command files
        const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));

        // Loop through all the files in ./commands
        for (const file of files) {
            // Get the status of 'file' (is it a file or directory?)
            const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));

            // If the 'file' is a directory, call the 'readCommands' function
            // again with the path of the subdirectory
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                readCommands(path.join(dir, file));
            }
            else {
                const fileDir = dir.replace('\\', '/');
                fileArray.push(fileDir + '/' + file);
                // fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(cmdFile => cmdFile.endsWith('.js'));
            }
        }
    }   
};
```

I think the comments are explaining the process pretty well. But let's move on!

---

After you pasted that into your project you still need to call the `readCommands()` function...

```js
readCommands('commands');

    for(const file of fileArray) {
        const command = require(`../${file}`);

        if(command.name) {
            client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        }       
    }
```

The parameter `commands` is the name of your **root command folder**. So if you decide to give it another name, e.g. 'commandFolder', you need to pass that name as parameter!

#### But dont copy & paste it yet! I want you to understand how this works:

In the **command handler code**, rigth underneath the `module.exports` I'm creating an **array** called `fileArray`. This stores all your **command files** the code above has found. **Now** we **loop through** this **array**, **import** the command and **check** if it's empty or not.

If it's **not** empty, we'll **set** this command to `client.commands`, so you can **get** it later in your code, when you need to **execute** it.

#### If you know how it works...

...you can paste this into the same file as the 'main code' of the **command handler**, so that both code snippets are in the same file. Also make sure to paste this **inside of** the `module.exports` block, not outside of it ;)